# Вывести как ссылку то, что пользователь добавит

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать так чтобы выводило как ссылку то, что пользователь добавит (чтобы он добавлял свой id в контакте) и в каталоге появилась с ним а кнопка добавить и будет открываться его страница в контакте) в новой вкладке ! и так что бы отображались только последние 10 и с верху появлялись новые

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Piar</title>
<style>
#centerLayer {
position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
width: 420px; /* Ширина слоя в пикселах */
height: 980px; /* Высота слоя в пикселах */
margin-left: 280px; /* Отступ слева */
margin-top: 45px; /* Отступ сверху */
background: #f5f5f5; /* Цвет фона */
overflow: auto; /* Добавление полосы прокрутки */ 
}
h2 {
font-size: 1.5em; /* Размер шрифта */
color: #007aab; /* Цвет текста */
margin-top: 0; /* Отступ сверху */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="logo.png">
<div id="centerLayer">
<h2>Обмен Друзьями ! </h2>
<br><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?109"></script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$users_id=file('id.txt');
$_POST['id']=str_replace('http','',$_POST['id']);
$_POST['id']=str_replace('https','',$_POST['id']);
$_POST['id']=str_replace(':','',$_POST['id']);
$_POST['id']=str_replace('/','',$_POST['id']);
$_POST['id']=str_replace('id','',$_POST['id']);
$_POST['id']=str_replace('vk.com','',$_POST['id']);
$users_id[]=$_POST['id']."\n";
$fp=fopen('id.txt','w');
fputs($fp,implode('',$users_id));
fclose($fp);
}

$id=file('id.txt');
$id=str_replace("\n",'',$id);
$count=sizeof($id);
for($i=$count;$i>=$count-10;--$i)
{
echo <a href=".$i.">Добавить (его/ее)</a>;
}
?>
<br>
<form method="post" >
<input type="text" placeholder="Ваш ID ВКонтакте" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form> 
<br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @arthru, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку **{}** редактора.

Comment: @arthru, постарайтесь четче сформулировать задачу.  

Вы хотите, чтобы пользователи могли добавиться в какой-то каталог и чтобы в нем выводились ссылки на профили последних 10 добавившихся пользователей? По клику на профиль пользователя он должен открываться в новой вкладке. Так?

Comment: Да так !!!